# While-Loop Confusion

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I'm trying to create a while-loop that calculates the stopping power and range of a heavy charged particle using the Bethe-Bloch equation. I'm having trouble setting up the loop to save for each value as the loop iterates.

The idea is that I have an equation Stopping Power (-dEdx) that spits out a value for how much energy is lost over dx, when given an initial energy value.

In the example code here, the initial Energy = 250 (MeV), and I'm attempting to calculate the new energy for each dx. This should look something like
E = 250, 249.99, 249.96, etc
I'm not 100% sure if the loop has any other issues, but I mainly can't figure out how to keep each individual value of E, so that I can plot what happens to the energy over the total distance, x.

The formula seems to spit out only 1 value for E, and doesn't fill in all the other columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
clear
clc

c = 2.998e10;
pm = 938.272; % proton mass
em = 0.510991; % electron mass
re = 2.818e-13; % classical electron radius
z = 1; % charge of proton (+)
na = 6.022e23; % avagadros number
rho = 1;
dx = 0.01;
x = 0:dx:350;    % 350mm = 35cm
n = na.*10./18.*rho;
E = x*0;
E(1) = 250;

while E > 0
    gam = E./pm + 1;
    beta = sqrt(gam.^2-1)./gam;
    dEdx = (4.*pi.*n.*z^2.*em.*re.^2)./beta.*(log(2.*em.*c.^2.*beta.^2./(75.*(1-beta.^2)))-beta.^2);
    dE = -dEdx.*dx;
    E(x(E)) = E(x(E)) + dE;
end
```

It might be useful to hold on to all values of gam,beta,dEdx,dE,E for each iteration. e.g. 
E = [250, 249.99, 249.96, ..., 0]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the line `E(x(E)) = E(x(E)) + dE;`

When you run your loop, E=250 and there is only 1 element in E so x(E) is some number (the 250th element of x) and then E(x(E)) is the element of E with that index.  In general, this would cause an error since x(E) is not guaranteed to be an integer in your example but also it's just not doing what you want it to do.  In order to accomplish your goal, you need an index variable:

```
index=1;
E(index)=250;

while E(index) > 0
    gam = E(index)/pm + 1;
    beta = sqrt(gam^2-1)/gam;
    dEdx = (4.*pi.*n.*z^2.*em.*re.^2)./beta.*(log(2.*em.*c.^2.*beta.^2./(75.*(1-beta.^2)))-beta.^2);
    dE = -dEdx*dx;
    E(index+1) = E(index) + dE;
    index=index+1;
end
```

There's also another inconsistency you might want to address.  You're setting x up ahead of time with a fixed maximum but you're not enforcing that maximum when calculating E.  If you want to use the while loop and be sure to get the full decay of E you shouldn't define x ahead of time and instead create it at the end after you know who long it needs to be.  Alternatively, if you only want to go to a maximum value of x you could use a for loop instead of a while loop and you would have your index variable built in.

Comment: Hi John, that worked perfectly. I just added the index to all the variables and initialized them all and it looks like I can do everything I need to do with the code. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling onto this question looking at a similar issue, here is the updated code that looks to be working perfectly thanks to John who answered the question.

```
clear
clc

c = 2.998e10;
pm = 938.272; % proton mass
em = 0.510991; % electron mass
re = 2.818e-13; % classical electron radius
z = 1; % charge of proton (+)
na = 6.022e23; % avagadros number
rho = 1;
dx = 0.01;
x = 0:dx:350;    % Expected Maximum range: 350mm = 35cm
n = na.*10./18.*rho;

dEdx = x*0;
dE = x*0;
E = x*0;

i = 1;
E(i) = 250;

while E(i) > 0
    gam = E./pm + 1;
    beta = sqrt(gam.^2-1)./gam;
    dEdx = ((4.*pi.*n.*z^2.*em.*re.^2)./beta).*(log(2.*em.*c.^2.*beta.^2./...
    (75.*(1-beta.^2)))-beta.^2);

    dE(i) = -dEdx(i).*dx;
    E(i+1) = E(i) + dE(i);
    i = i + 1;
end
```

Comment: You may be missing a (i) on the lines where you set dEdx and where you set gam

Comment: It is sort of working without it. The values in dEdx change from dEdx(0) until E = 0, and then all remaining values of dEdx = -inf
When I try to change it to dEdx(i) it gives me an error "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same. Error in test_exact_example (line 25)
    dEdx(i) = ((4.*pi.*n.*z^2.*em.*re.^2)./beta).*(log(2.*em.*c.^2.*beta.^2./..."

Comment: That's because you have gam as a vector instead of a scalar so it's assigning a full vector to dEdx at each pass through the loop.